# QtQuick: Drawing a Line - Mixing QQuickItem with Canvas or QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I created a QQuickItem which can display a lineplot. This has been done using QSGNodes and should thus be hardware accelerated via OpenGL (as I need to plot many points). Now I want to add an axes to this this plot, and for this I need to draw some lines for the Axis, Ticks (and maybe include a svg for the Arrow head on the axis) and have some text labels.

Does it hurt performance, if I implement this axis as a QQuickPaintedItem or using the Canvas? I am not worried about the performance of drawing the axis, but would my lineplot QQuickItem still be using OpenGL if there is a QQuickPaintedItem at the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that SVG files are rasterized and drawn as raster bitmaps, they are not drawn using geometry, so having a SVG won't really save you much aside from the space the image takes on disk, as far as the GPU rendering is concerned, it is just a bitmap. If you want to draw it using geometry, go for `QQuickItem` and `QSGNodes` combo again.

`QQuickPaintedItem` or `Canvas`- both work in the same way, only the drawing for `Canvas` is done from JS, so it will be a tad slower. However, it may be a non issue as you typically don't have to redraw chart axis that much.

Of course, each element will be rendered with its respective backend, no need for concern there.